# Map function TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

i have a list of object :

```
let pages = [{'Home': ['exapmle 1', 'exapmle 2', 'exapmle 3']},
{'Services': ['exapmle 1', 'exapmle 2', 'exapmle 3']},
{'Technologies': ['exapmle 1', 'exapmle 2', 'exapmle 3']},
{'Insights': ['exapmle 1', 'exapmle 2', 'exapmle 3']},
{'Career': ['exapmle 1', 'exapmle 2', 'exapmle 3']},
{'About Us': []}];
```

i whould like to get Home, Services, Insights ... as string and ['exapmle 1', 'exapmle 2', 'exapmle 3'] as array of string

```
  {pages.map((page) => (
                                <Box sx={{flexGrow: 0}}>
                                    <Button onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{p: 0}}>
                                        {Object.keys(page)[0]}
                                    </Button>
                                    <DropDown item={page[])} anchorElUser={anchorElUser} handleCloseUserMenu={() => {
                                        setAnchorElUser(null);
                                    }}/>
                                </Box>
                            ))}
```

Comment: where do you want that? be more descriptive and explain the issue you are facing.

Comment: see map type signature. if i understand correctly, this isn't a map problem, but a reduce problem. the question needs to be explained further though, and the code example seems unrelated.

Comment: Looks like your code works as expected and the array of buttons will each have the desired string. I think the issue maybe that your dropdown is also inside of the map?

Answer (score 0):

thanks you guys ,
Problem resolved .

```
 {pages.map((page) => (
              <Box key={page.name} sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
                <>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleOpenUserMenu}>
                        <Typography textAlign="center">
                            <p>  {page.name}</p>
                        </Typography>
                    </MenuItem>
                  <DropDown
                    item={page.subPages}
                    anchorElUser={anchorElUser}
                    handleCloseUserMenu={() => {
                      setAnchorElUser(null);
                    }}
                  />
                </>
              </Box>
            ))}
```

Comment: type Page = { name: string; subPages: string[] };

type Pages = Page[];

const pages: Pages = [
  { name: 'Home', subPages: ['exapmle 1', 'exapmle 2', 'exapmle 3'] },
  { name: 'Services', subPages: ['exapmle 1', 'exapmle 2', 'exapmle 3'] },
  { name: 'Technologies', subPages: ['exapmle 1', 'exapmle 2', 'exapmle 3'] },
  { name: 'Insights', subPages: ['exapmle 1', 'exapmle 2', 'exapmle 3'] },
  { name: 'Career', subPages: ['exapmle 1', 'exapmle 2', 'exapmle 3'] },
  { name: 'About Us', subPages: ['exapmle 1', 'exapmle 2', 'exapmle 3'] },
];